# How to create Yes / No?

Tags: java, class, if-statement, input

So this code allows the users to save their object, created in the main. However I wish to create a function (if statement I think) which will ask the users whether they wish to save it (results.txt). If they do then save, if not then exit the program.

```
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class Main {
        public static void main( String args[] ) {

            Person arthur = new Person();

            arthur.name = "Arthur Dent";
            arthur.age= 21;

            System.out.println("\nDo you wish to save these results? (Y / N)");

            String fileName = "results.txt";
            try {   

                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));

                os.writeObject(arthur); //write object
                os.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            System.out.println("\nYour results are saved!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to prompt the user or create the `if` statement?

Comment: Format your code properly before posting it here please. You can use this online tool to do that: http://codebeautify.org/javaviewer

Comment: Look at the Scanner class `new Scanner (System.in);`

Comment: Something like [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) and [Scanner Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) might help

Comment: You can also use System.console(). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Comment: `System.console() ` will return `null` in many IDE's without some hacking, but it is another solution.

Comment: I'm still unsure, any help please?

Comment: System.console() does not let me go to the next object.

Comment: @ScottAllen Some IDEs return null for `System.console()`. If that's the case with your IDE, as suggested by @ScaryWombat, you can use `Scanner` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) approach. An example of how Scanner works (applied to your question):

```
public class Test2 {
    static Boolean bool=true;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Type Y or N:");
        //Initialise the scanner object for the first time
        //Save what the user inputs as s
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=sc.next();
        //Now you enter a while loop
        //You will quit this loop if a condition is met
        //If you want to you can set the bool to false and the while loop will end
        while (bool){
            //if what the user entered is not equal to Y or N
            //then prompt him to try again
            if (!s.equals("Y") && !s.equals("N")){
                System.out.println("Please type only Y or N:");
                sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                s=sc.next();

            }
            //if the user actually entered Y
            if (s.equals("Y")){
                //Do your code logic here
                //In your case that is saving your object
                //Then you can exit the program if that's what you want
                System.exit(1);

            }
            if (s.equals("N")){
                //Add code logic if the user enters N if you need to
                //Exit the program if that's what you want
                System.exit(1);         
            }
        }                       
    }
}
```

If you play with the above code you will quickly be able to integrate it to your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you comment a couple of lines for this class, so i have a better understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: Also What do you mean by //Do you saves here? What do i put there?

Comment: I've added some comments for you.